# Java ArrayList without "direct access"

Tags: java, list, arraylist, null

I have an instance attribute

```
private ArrayList<String> list;
```

which is set by the constructor. I want to prevent that this list from containing nulls, so I wrote my own `add()` and `remove()` methods for the list, and I remove all null elements from the list in the constructor.

Now nobody should get direct access to this list, to prevent them from simply adding null.

```
public class TestList {
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    
    public TestList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        while (list.remove(null));
        this.list = list;
    }
    
    public List<String> getList() { //Just for the test code
        return list;
    }
    
    public boolean add(String e) {
        if (e == null) {
            return false;
        }
        
        return list.add(e);
    }
    
    public boolean remove(String e) {
        return list.remove(e);
    }
}
```

But with this class I still have access to the list as you can see in the following test code.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("line0");
list.add("line1");
list.add("line2");
TestList tl = new TestList(list);
list.add(null);
System.out.println(tl.getList().toString());
```

Console: `[line0, line1, line2, null]`

As you can see, null was added to the list, because I have still a reference to the list in the class outside of the class. (I am not sure if this explanation is 100% right, but in principle I understand this)

My solution for this problem:

```
public class TestList {
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    
    public TestList(ArrayList<String> list) {
        ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(list);
        while (newList.remove(null));
        this.list = newList;
    }
    
    public List<String> getList() { //Just for the test code
        return list;
    }
    
    public boolean add(String e) {
        if (e == null) {
            return false;
        }
        
        return list.add(e);
    }
    
    public boolean remove(String e) {
        return list.remove(e);
    }
}
```

Test with the same code: `[line0, line1, line2]`, so now it works correctly.

#### My question(s):

- Is this code bad practice?
- Are there any better solutions?

All comments and tips welcome.

Comment: You're making a shallow copy of the list which I believe is a fine thing to do. You can even do the same if you want to return a copy of the List to another object.

Comment: Note: I've edited your question and have removed your apology about "bad English". Your English is perfectly fine, and so there is no need for this.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I plan to do (the part with return a copy ...) thank you for your answer.

Comment: you can still do `new TestList(someArrayList).getList().add(null)` because `getList` returns the internal list. I would override `ArrayList` instead. (one of the reason being the ability to use it where a `List` is expected, something you cannot do with your current implementation)

Comment: Oh sorry, I added getList() just for the test code, it should not be there. Edit: And it would work with: return new ArrayList<String>(list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have implemented the [*delegation* software design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).

To complete your class's intention, employ "safe publishing", which returns a *copy* of the internal data structure (albeit a *shallow* copy):

```
public List<String> getList() {
    return new ArrayList<>(list);
}
```

The client can then do what they like with the list without affecting your list.
Alternatively, you can return an immutable list:

```
public List<String> getList() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}
```

Which will throw an exception if an attempt is made to modify it.

---

btw, from a coding style perspective, you may consider this "optimization":

```
if (e == null) {
    return false;
}

return list.add(e);
```

can be rewritten as one line:

```
return e != null && list.add(e);
```